# print layout not equal to screen layout

Tags: printing

I have a problem with printing from HTML.
First of all I create a print preview page. Everything works well.
When I go to print only the part that interests me (sequence of A4 pages), only the first page is divided into two, it seems that a 'padding-top' is imposed higher than the imposed one. Basically the first footer is moved to the next page.
Here are two images, screen and print.
[image][image]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Report</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    @*librerie per abilitare la selezione delle righe*@
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    @*libreria per stilizzare una select*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>*@

    <style type="text/css">
        @@Media print {
            #ScreenDiv {
                visibility: hidden;
                display: none;
            }
            #PrintDiv {
                visibility: visible;
                display: normal;
            }

            page {
                background: white;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0cm;
                padding-left: 2cm;
                padding-top: 1cm;
                padding-right: 2cm;
                padding-bottom: 0cm;
                /*https://github.com/delight-im/HTML-Sheets-of-Paper/blob/gh-pages/css/sheets-of-paper-a4.css*/
            }

                page[size="A4"] {
                    width: 21cm;
                    height: 29.7cm;
                }

                    page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
                        width: 29.7cm;
                        height: 21cm;
                    }

           .panel-footer {
                page-break-after: always;
            }
        }
        @@media screen{
            #ScreenDiv {
                visibility: visible;
                display: normal;
            }
            #PrintDiv {
                visibility: hidden;
                display: none;
            }

            page {
                background: white;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 80px;
                margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                padding-left: 2cm;
                padding-top: 1cm;
                padding-right: 2cm;
                padding-bottom: 0cm;
                /*https://github.com/delight-im/HTML-Sheets-of-Paper/blob/gh-pages/css/sheets-of-paper-a4.css*/
            }

                page[size="A4"] {
                    width: 21cm;
                    height: 29.7cm;
                }

                    page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
                        width: 29.7cm;
                        height: 21cm;
                    }
        }

        h3 {
            margin-top: 0px;
            color: dodgerblue !important;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .col-fixed-30 {
            width: 30%;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: white;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .row-fixed-70 {
            height: 70px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: white;
            width: 70%;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .col-offset-30 {
            padding-left: 30%;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ScreenDiv">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-fixed-30" style="padding:2px">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:30px; color:dodgerblue">Lista Report<span class="badge badge-default"></span></h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="AnnoSelect" name="AnnoSelect" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple title="Selezionare Anno"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="TipoIspezioneSelect" name="AnnoSelect" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" title="Selezionare Tipo Ispezione">
                            <option value="Ispezione Corrente">Ispezione Corrente</option>
                            <option value="Ispezione Corrente Straordinaria">Ispezione Corrente Straordinaria</option>
                            <option value="Ispezione Qualitativa">Ispezione Qualitativa</option>
                            <option value="Ispezione Dettagliata">Ispezione Dettagliata</option>
                            <option value="Ispezione Dettagliata Eccezionale">Ispezione Dettagliata Eccezionale</option>
                            <option value="Sorveglianza Speciale">Sorveglianza Speciale</option>
                            <option value="Sorveglianza Intensificata">Sorveglianza Intensificata</option>
                            <option value="Alta Sorveglianza">Alta Sorveglianza</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="TipoOperaSelect" name="TipoOperaSelect" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" title="Selezionare Tipo Opera">
                            <option value="null">Da Gestire</option>
                            <option value="true">Approvate</option>
                            <option value="false">Rifiutate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="ElementoSelect" name="ElementoSelect" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" title="Selezionare Tipo Elemento">
                            <option value="null">Da Gestire</option>
                            <option value="true">Approvate</option>
                            <option value="false">Rifiutate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Stampa1">
                                        Collapsible Group 1
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Stampa1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <button id="StampaReport" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Stampa Report </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Stampa2">
                                        Collapsible Group 2
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Stampa2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    seconda Stampa
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="LayoutArea" class="col-md-12 col-offset-30" style="background-color:lightgray">
                <div class="row row-fixed-70">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:30px; color:dodgerblue; text-align:center">Anteprima Report</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="LayoutStampa">
                    <page size="A4" id="page0">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="height:45px">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-bottom: .2em solid #aaaaaa;border-top: .2em hidden">
                                    <tr><td id="headerLeft" style="width:30%" align="left">left</td><td id="headerCenter" align="center">center</td><td id="headerRight" style="width:30%" align="right">right</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h3 id="TitoloPagina">Anteprima Report</h3>
                            <div class="table-responsive" style="height:24cm;background-color:red">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" border=0 cellpadding=20 cellspacing=0 style="border-bottom: .13em solid #aaaaaa;font-size:10px">
                                    @*<tr><th style="width:30%">#</th><th>name</th></tr>*@
                                    <tr align="center"><td style="width:30%">1</td><td>100</td><td style="width:30%">DONALD TRUMP</td></tr>
                                    <tr align="center"><td style="width:30%">2</td><td>100</td><td style="width:30%">BARACK OBAMA</td></tr>
                                    <tr align="center"><td style="width:30%">3</td><td>100</td><td style="width:30%">BARACK OBAMA</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer" style="height:45px">
                            <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-bottom: .2em solid #aaaaaa;border-top: .2em hidden">
                                <tr><td id="footerLeft" style="width:30%" align="left">left</td><td id="footerCenter" align="center">center</td><td id="footerRight" style="width:30%" align="right">right</td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </page>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="PrintDiv">

    </div>

    <script>
        var ListaOpere;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            var anno = d.getFullYear();
            for (var i = anno; i >= 1990; i--) {
                $("#AnnoSelect").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
            }

            $('#StampaReport').on('click', function () {
                var clone = $('#LayoutStampa').clone();
                $("#PrintDiv").append(clone);
                $('#LayoutStampa').remove();
                window.print();
                $("#LayoutStampa").remove();
                $('#LayoutArea').append(clone);
            })

            var testo = '<div class="panel-heading" style="height:45px">' +
                '< div class="table-responsive" >' +
                '<table class="table" style="border-bottom: .2em solid #aaaaaa;border-top: .2em hidden">' +
                '<tr><td align=left> left</td><td align=right> right</td></tr>' +
                '</table> </div > </div >'


            var cloneCount = 1;
            for (var i = cloneCount; i <= 10; i++) {
                var clone = $('#page0').clone();
                clone.attr('id', 'page' + i);
                clone.find('h3[id=TitoloPagina]').text('Titolo' + i);
                clone.find('td[id=headerLeft]').text('Macerata');
                $("#LayoutStampa").append(clone);
                //alert(i);
            }


            });
        </script>
</body>
</html >
```

Where is the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If imposed -60px on 'media print page margin-top', it adjusts everything.
But I realized that, all the solution, it does not work well on edge and explorer.